# Sporadic SMS on Galaxy Nexus after upgrade to 4.3?

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have an unlocked Galaxy Nexus I bought directly from Google and use a T-Mobile plan. Last week, I got the OTA update for 4.3. Since then, I haven't consistently been able to send text messages. The usual scenario is:

1. Send a text message.
2. It hangs at sending (Messaging eats up more battery than normal during this.)
3. It'll sit there indefinitely until I send another text. Tested this by waiting all day on two occasions.
4. After I send another text, either a.) that one hangs too or b.) that one, and any ones that are stuck at sending, will all simultaneously send. It's like the successive text wakes up all the other ones.

This happens enough to not be coincidence, and as I said I've let the stuck messages sit there for about eight hours without sending any more messages and they would not send until after I did. Anyone have any idea what's going on here?